# Refer week from another table to select

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a week range 3 weeks back from the current week that is set in another table.

The current week is set up in column 'c1' in table `t_whse_control` and I am looking results for 3 weeks back in column `week` for table `t_po_master`.

I've tried joining the two tables but I am not getting the results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_po_master pom
INNER JOIN t_whse_control whc 
ON pom.wh_id = whc.wh_id
WHERE whc.control_type = 'ACTIVE_INV_WEEK'
```

## t_whse_control

```
control_type           desc              c1

ACTIVE_INV_WEEK        abcdefg           201919
```

---

## t_po_master

```
Po_id                      po_number         status          week

1                            123456              C         201919
2                            234567              C         201918
3                            56789               C         201919
```

Comment: Can you substitute your sample data with cleaner names? The script here is so difficult to read I can't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Playing around with `DATEADD` and `DATEPART` might be a good start. Unfortunately, I cant be too sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a relationship that goes back three weeks you could use a DATEADD clause to add negative three weeks to your query. The result would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_po_master pom
INNER JOIN t_whse_control whc 
ON pom.wh_id = whc.wh_id
WHERE whc.control_type = 'ACTIVE_INV_WEEK'
AND pom.week = DATEADD(WEEK, -3, pom.week)
```

The pom.week column can be substituted for another DATETIME column if necessary, but there isn't enough script provided to make any assumptions.